# Как сделать шрифты?

Tags: шрифты, css

Как можно сделать шрифты, как [здесь](http://networkingday.ru/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: gotham_reg;
    src: url('http://networkingday.ru/Content/fonts/GothaProReg.otf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: gotham_bol;
    src: url('http://networkingday.ru/Content/fonts/GothaProBol.otf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: open_sanslight;
    src: url('http://networkingday.ru/Content/fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: alt_got_no_3d;
    src: url('http://networkingday.ru/Content/fonts/AlternateGotNo3D-Regular.ttf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: open_sans_bold;
    src: url('http://networkingday.ru/Content/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf');
}
```

Стащил с их сайта, Вам это надо? Извините, пишу с телефона, сайта не видел)